# R DBI issue with accessing list fields of a remote table

Tags: r, r-dbi, rjdbc

I am trying to get the fields of a table in an Arctic database. For that I've been successful at creating a `jdbcConnection` object which is of class "JDBCConnection", but once I write the following code to get the fields of the `AR_LOT` table (dbListFields comes from DBI package),

```
dbListFields(jdbcConnection, name = Id(schema = "ARCTIC", table = "AR_LOT"))
```

I get the following error message.

> Error in dbSendQuery(conn, paste("SELECT * FROM ", dbQuoteIdentifier(conn,  :
> Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
> JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> Statement: SELECT * FROM  "ARCTIC"."AR_LOT" LIMIT 0

I also tried with RJDBC's function `dbGetFields`, but I'm also running into an error.

> Error in .jcall(md, "Ljava/sql/ResultSet;", "getColumns", .jnull("java/lang/String"),  :
> method getColumns with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet; not found

The weird thing is that `dbReadTable` from DBI package works just fine.

Can anyone please help me understand these error messages a little more clearly? Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you execute that query directly: `dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 'select * from "ARCTIC"."AR_LOT" LIMIT 0')`?

Comment: Please show the working `dbReadTable` line. Are you using `Id()`? What does `dbListTables` and `dbListObjects` show?

Comment: @langtang I get Error in dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

  Statement: select * from "ARCTIC"."AR_LOT" LIMIT 0

Comment: dbReadTable does output the right table, and this is how I'm constructing that `dbReadTable(jdbcConnection, name = Id(schema = "ARCTIC", table = "AR_LOT"))`. And as for dbListTables I'm just passing the connection and I'm getting back some random tables that I guess live somewhere in the various schemas

Comment: this might be a dumb suggestion, but what if you add `;` to the end of the statement (i.e. `dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 'select * from "ARCTIC"."AR_LOT" LIMIT 0;')?

Comment: @langtang pretty much the same error (except ; at the end too)

Comment: hmm, sorry, I'm not sure.. I assume it can't return LIMIT 1, either?

Comment: @langtang yes it doesn't seem to return limit 1 either, I just don't get this JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933

Comment: FWIW, the following worked for me in an Oracle DB: `DBI::dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, statement = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AR_LOT'")[, 1L]`. I ran into the exact same issues with `DBI::dbListFields()` and `RJDBC::dbGetFields()` before that.